# Converting a decimal/floating point value to Hexadecimal value that conforms to IEEE754 standard

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I’m looking for some C# source code that would convert a decimal/floating point value to Hexadecimal value that conforms to IEEE754 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Covert hax to Single precision , steps are below

1. Conevrt decimal to string using X format provider
2. convert hax into byte array
3. Convert binary into byte for all elements in array
4. convert to single

   ```
   decimal decValue = 989.99M;
   string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
   //Convert to float(24)/Single-precision floating-point format/ IEEE 754-2008/ binary32.

   byte[] raw = new byte[hexValue.Length / 2];
   for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
   {
       raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
       raw[raw.Length - i - 1] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
   }

   float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(raw, 0);
   ```